# How to use Bernoulli equation in a rotating frame and is it always true that bernoulli will work?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, flow, centrifugal-force, bernoulli-equation

Lets say a fluid is rotating in a cylindrical shape container with every circular fluid streamline rotating with same $w$ by some external mechanism, now imagine asking for pressure difference between two points on a circular cross section of container, how will one apply bernoulli in rotating frame as such ik its validity is here using some pseudo potential energy term, can anyone explain how it will work?

Answer (score 1):

The Bernoulli equation is a statement of conservation of energy from: pressure, velocity and elevation. But a specific limitation on the equation is for the effects of "centrifugal force" in curved flow. Also this is not really a case of fluid flow as such because each element of fluid maintains its position in the container (apart from convection). There is no exchange between the three types of energy as the element moves in a circle. Also there is no energy being imparted to the system as a whole, but the velocity of the fluid increases linearly with distance from the centre of rotation, so therefore the kinetic energy of a particle increases with the square of the distance.

The terms $P$ and ${\rho}gh$ account for the linear change in hydrostatic pressure with height (as the elevation decreases the pressure increases), but separately there is an increase in pressure due to velocity: ${\rho}v^2/2 = {\rho}r^2{\omega}^2/2$. If the Bernoulli equation applied, the hydrostatic pressure would have to decrease as the velocity pressure increased away from the centre, which clearly does not happen. So in this case the total energy is not the same for all particles, it is greater, further from the centre.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to think of the Bernoulli equation in the rotating frame of reference. If the cylinder is rotating at angular velocity omega, define the reference frame so that the cylinder is static. There is a good derivation by Professor McDonald of Princeton University at http://kirkmcd.princeton.edu/examples/bernoulli_rot.pdf using Newtonian analysis of motion of a packet of fluid. The fluid is in solid body rotation so the $V^2/2$ term vanishes. We get:

$P - \frac{\rho \omega^2 r^2}{2} + \rho gz = const.$

The expression $P - \frac{\rho \omega^2 r^2}{2}$ is usually called the *reduced pressure*, i.e. the pressure minus the contribution from centrifugal force. It can be thought of as the pressure that drives fluid motions relative to the reference frame.

In this form we see that moving from a smaller to a larger radius increases the pressure, as it should. It also shows that the reduced pressure is constant at a depth $z$ and increases with decreasing $z$.

What I want to know is how to frame the problem when the fluid *isn't* in solid body rotation, i.e. when the velocity relative to the reference frame is nonzero. I think that the $\rho V^2/2$ term is reintroduced but I haven't confirmed it by Newtonian analysis.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/410978)